# Prove $f$ is diagonalizable iff $V=W \oplus Z$ where $W,Z \subseteq V$ are $f$ invariant

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $K$ be field algebraically closed, $f\in End(V)$ prove:

$f$ is diagonalizable $\iff$ $\forall W \subset V$ invarant under $f$ exist $Z \subset V$ invariant under $f$ such that $V=W\oplus Z$

i have olny idea with one directon namely assume that $f$ is diagonalizable then exist basis $A=\{v_1, .., v_n\}$ consisted with eigenvectors so choosing any subset of $A$ we have invariant subspace $W$ and we can pick $Z$ be taking the rest vectors from $A$ to take whole $V$, bu i'm not sure if it's works

Comment: I'm assuming $V$ is a vector space over $K$, is that right?. Are we only concerned with finite-dimensional vector spaces $V$ here? With your proof idea, you're *choosing* $W$, when you should be working with an arbitrary given $W \subseteq V$ that's invariant under $f$.

Comment: Yes V is vector space over K, yes only finite-dimensional. Can you show yours approach ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has essentially been asked on this site before.

- For the first direction, proof is here: [Existence of T-invariant complement of T-invariant subspace when T is diagonalisable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191741/existence-of-t-invariant-complement-of-t-invariant-subspace-when-t-is-diagonalis?rq=1)
- For the second direction, proof is here: [Proving a diagonal matrix exists for linear operators with complemented invariant subspaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/383970/proving-a-diagonal-matrix-exists-for-linear-operators-with-complemented-invarian?rq=1)

You can use the algebraic closedness of your field instead of the fundamental theorem of algebra. Otherwise the steps are the same.